# Comparing the supremum of Maclaurian series with the function.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Suppose $f$ is an entire funciton with the Maclaurin Series $$a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots $$
Show that if $r>0$ then 
$$|a_0|^2+|a_1|^2|r|^2+|a_2|^2|r|^4+|a_3|^2|r|^6+\cdots < \sup_{|z|=r} |f(z)|^2 $$

So I computed the Maclaurian series of $f^2$ using power series multiplication. I cant see any any leads there. I am guessing there is some theorem that I need to know that will crack this in one line? Any hints?

Comment: Since we are bounding coefficients of a Taylor series, the Cauchy estimates come to mind. Not sure if useful though.

Comment: False as stated. You need $|a_n|^2$ everywhere. Then on the LHS you have $(1/2\pi)\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2\,dt,$ etc.